# как изменить значение переменной с помощью функции? Python, pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-menu

```py
menu.append_option('Restart', )
```

мне нужно, чтобы после запятой значение переменной менялось, если записать

```py
menu.append_option('Restart', a = 1)
```

появится ошибка:

```py
    menu.append_option('Restart', a = 1)
TypeError: Menu.append_option() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

может помочь кто-то?

Comment: для чего нужна эта переменная?

Comment: Переменная `a` у вас где вообще - в этой вызываемой функции или там, где эта функция вызывается?

Answer (score 1):

Использование записи формата `a = 1` в аргументах вызова функции, интерпретатор расценивает как попытку передать именованный параметр в функцию. В данном случае поможет использование [walrus operator](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-3-8-new-features-the-walrus-operator-and-positional-only-parameters-e7333eb8be2a).

```
menu.append_option('Restart', a := 1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но теперь новая проблема
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\game\game.py", line 93, in <module>
    menu.select()
  File "c:\game\game.py", line 67, in select
    self._callbacks[self._current_option_index](1)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable```

Comment: @jiwi_X это уже ошибка у тебя в коде, в том числе указано где конкретно: `File "c:\game\game.py", line 93, in <module>     menu.select()   File "c:\game\game.py", line 67, in select`. Либо отредактируй этот вопрос, либо пометь ответ засчитанным и создай новый вопрос, только уже со всеми подробностями этой ошибки, включая код программы.